# Run tdpsql command from powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that requires 3 mandatory input parameters that will be used to run the backup  command for tdpsql.

1. type (FULL, DIFF or LOG)
2. SQLServerinstancename
3. Database (SYSTEM, ALL, )

Within the powershell script I have the following line

```
$cmd = "C:\Progra~1\Tivoli\TSM\TDPSql\tdpsqlc.exe backup " + $idatabase + " " + $action + " " + $parameter + " /LOGFILE=" + $logdir + $logfile + "" $tdpsqlexe - The tdpsqlc exe.
$idatabase - Database name 
$action = FULL\DIFF\LOG
$parameter = /sqlserver=TCP:" + $sqlserverinstance + " /SQLAUTH=INT /TSMOPTFile='" + $dsmoptfilename + "' /EXCLUDEDB=" + $exclude

& $cmd
```

When I echo the command it reports out what I use to run it using powershell command line but when I try to run it from Powershell with the & it fails with the following

> The term
>
> > C:\Progra~1\Tivoli\TSM\TDPSql\tdpsqlc.exe
> >     backup master FULL
> >     /sqlserver=TCP:
> >     /SQLAUT H=INT
> >     /TSMOPTFile=C:\Progra~1\Tivoli\TSM\TDPSql\dsm.opt /EXCLUDEDB=tempdb /LOGFILE=`<logfile>`
>
> is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program.Check the spelling of
>   the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At TDPSQLBackup.ps1:166
>   char:6
>   +     & <<<<  $cmd >> test2.txt
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound:
>   (C:\Progra~1\Tiv...forsqlimran.txt:String)
>   [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might try `Invoke-Expression $cmd` instead of `& $cmd.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes better use `Invoke-Expression`, but if you still want to use & you can do it in this way.

```
$cmd = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
$params = "C:\temp\file.txt"

& $cmd $params
```

Using a var for program file ans a var for parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a batch command you'd better try Powershell cmdlets as follow

```
import-module "C:\Program Files\Tivoli\Flashcopymanager\fmmodulemmc.dll"
import-module "C:\Program Files\Tivoli\Flashcopymanager\fmmoduleSQL.dll"

$startTime = get-date
Backup-DpSqlComponent -Name AdventureWorks2012 -BackupDestination TSM -BackupMethod Legacy -Full
$endTime = get-date

$activity = Get-FcmMmcActivity -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime
$activity
```

Reference link
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21974345